# Cannot transfer data from backend to frontend via example code in latest api

Tags: node.js, electron

The example code for the latest api of contents.send() here: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-arg1-arg2-

I am simply trying to read a json file, send that data to the front end, and use the front end to visualize the data.

YET, the example code errors stating that require() is not a function on the frontend.

How am I supposed to read the data on the side of the frontend with a  tag if this api instruction is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Electron >5` then you need to set `nodeintegration:true`

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })

    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
    win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win.webContents.send('ping', 'whoooooooh!')
    })
});
```